problems with ubuntu upgrade
Today I upgraded to the newer version of ubuntu- stupidly I had other stuff downloading in the background and files coppying to a hard drive as I was backing up (I thought I was only downloading the upgrade not installing)- now I have errors, vlc player wont work or will brave browser- my error message in the top right corner says Error : BrokenCount > O, can someone please give me advice on how to reinstall packages for ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS to resolve this issue?  Thanks in advance
